# simple messaging database design for text messages

Tags: android, database-design

I want to make a simple database model for sms messages , i have the following model is it good or is there a better way to model them .

```
sms_message(_id,conversation_id,sender_id,time,text)

conversations(_id,last_msg_id,opposite_user_id,msges_counter_inside,has_new_msg_flag)

contacts(_id, display_name)

phone_numbers(user_id,phone_no)
```

I want to make it as sms message app on android

Comment: Why don't you use ContentProvider i.e. default tables for messaging on android,in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing databases, it is a good practice using **singular names for the tables and columns**. Otherwise it may cause confusion because when you retrieve records, you do not know if it is for just one object or many, and remember that the columns should be atomic (just one value). So, for example, use `phone_number` instead of `phone_numbers`.

Without knowing the hole scenario, the rest of the design seems good, as you separate the different elements in separate tables and relate them. (Do not forget to use foreign keys, primary keys and so on to keep your integrity ok!)